# Python requests module does not work for url with path

Tags: python, proxy, python-requests

My Python version is 2.7, and running on a Ubuntu machine. I am trying to use requests to get some page via a proxy server, it does not work for urls with full path. Here is an example to show this problem,

```
In [30]: proxies
Out[30]: {'http': 'http://webproxyserver.info:80'}

In [31]: url = 'http://api.mongodb.org/'

In [32]: r = requests.get(url,proxies = proxies)

In [33]: r.status_code
Out[33]: 200

In [34]: url_1 = 'http://api.mongodb.org/python'

In [35]: r = requests.get(url_1,proxies = proxies)

In [36]: r.status_code
Out[36]: 404
```

I am not sure if this is a problem of the proxy? Or something wrong with my Python code. It looks like the proxy only word for the main domain (without any path).

Thanks for any information.

--- updated at 05/11
I just realized the proxy server doesn't work at all. I got the proxy server from proxy4free, and looks like they are not a real proxy server, they are some websites that work like a browser.

I have tried another real proxy server, and the code is all good to execute. Thanks for all your information.

Comment: The code looks ok to me

Answer (score 1):

looks like something is wrong with the proxy server, i think its not able to process the `302` thrown by `http://api.mongodb.org/python`

```
$export http_proxy=                                                      
$curl -s -w '%{http_code}\n' 'http://api.mongodb.org/' -o /dev/null      
200
$curl -s -w '%{http_code}\n' 'http://api.mongodb.org/python' -o /dev/null
302
$export http_proxy='http://webproxyserver.info:80'                       
$curl -s -w '%{http_code}\n' 'http://api.mongodb.org/' -o /dev/null      
200
$curl -s -w '%{http_code}\n' 'http://api.mongodb.org/python' -o /dev/null
404
```

Answer (score 0):

Despite their name, webproxyserver.info do not operate an http proxy at that location. If you examine `r.text`, you'll see that the proxy doesn't work for any address, with or without a path.

Comment: Yes, you are correct. The proxy server URL is not working at all.